# Is it ok to say 'adorable time'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

According to Cambridge Dictionary,

*Adorable* means: **used to describe someone or something that makes you love or like them, usually because they are attractive and often small.**

I was wondering if I can say: It was an adorable time with my family.

Comment: It is not a common expression and I doubt *attractive and small* will be how your listeners interpret it.  You had *an attractive and small **time***?  It will most like be interpreted as *had a wonderful time* or something close to that.  Maybe, *I had a wonderful time with my adorable family.*

Comment: You can use this phrase, and people will understand it as you mean it.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - What is meant by *adorable time*?  You mean the family was adorable and so the time was also adorable by association.    In my experience *Time* is never adorable.  *Adorable* is almost always associated with some physical traits or behaviors.  Time has no such traits or behaviors.

Comment: This may be too much of an "opinion" question, unfortunately.

Comment: @EllieK We had a wonderful time. This works the same way. It is clear and grammatical.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - wonderful <> adorable.  *We had a chewable time visiting the gum factory,* is also clear and grammatical, unfortunately its meaning is muddled and I wouldn't suggest speaking this way.

Comment: @EllieK No, I do not mean that the family was adorable. I meant that the time we spent was adorable. I am very well aware that wonderful is not equal to adorable. I do not agree and you will not convince me, so move along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a strange phrase.  It's understandable, but it sounds weird, because *adorable* is usually applied to people or animals or behaviors, or at least concrete nouns, but not times.

If we look at [Google Ngrams for nouns used with *adorable* in the last 20 years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adorable%20*_NOUN&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), we see that the most common are

- baby
- smile
- child/children
- face
- way
- thing
- creature
- girl
- woman

As you can see, only one, or maybe two, of those (*way*, *thing*) is not a concrete noun.

[If we compare "adorable time" to "adorable *man/thought/table*"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time%3D%3Eadorable%2Cman%3D%3Eadorable%2Ctable%3D%3Eadorable%2Cthought%3D%3Eadorable&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctime%3D%3Eadorable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cman%3D%3Eadorable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctable%3D%3Eadorable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthought%3D%3Eadorable%3B%2Cc0), to use three words that didn't even appear in the first list, we can see that "adorable time" is barely more common than "adorable table"!

[If we compare "adorable time" to *wonderful, lovely, amazing, fantastic, cute,* or *charming* time, we can see that it is the least common word.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wonderful%20time%2Camazing%20time%2Clovely%20time%2Cfantastic%20time%2Ccute%20time%2Ccharming%20time%2Cadorable%20time&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwonderful%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camazing%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clovely%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfantastic%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccute%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccharming%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadorable%20time%3B%2Cc0)

---

**Conclusion: it is just not an idiomatic way to use the word.**